# Is there a way to extract all of the dates from a string in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For a given string, is it possible to count (and maybe extract) how many dates there are in there? As an example, the string may look like `(2019-06-01, 2019-06-02, 2019-06-03)` or `(This is the first date: 2019-06-01; This is the second date: 2019-06-02)` or in some other form. In the first one, it should return 3. And it should return 2 in the second example text.

I'm not sure where to start with this one. Is this possible in Redshift/PostgreSQL?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you mention postgres? are you thinking of migrating to postgres? extracting may be possible with a python udf. is there a maximum number of dates you might get e.g. 10?

Comment: Since Redshift was built using an older version of PostgreSQL, I just mentioned that just in case if there wasn't a solution in Redshift, I could maybe get an idea from a solution from a new version of PostgreSQL if someone were to post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
select regexp_count(str_field, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}') from your table
```

To test I have used this

```
with test_data as (
select '2019-06-01, 2019-06-02, 2019-06-03' str_field union all
select 'This is the first date: 2019-06-01; This is the second date: 2019-06-02'
)
select regexp_count(str_field, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}') date_count from test_data
```

The result is

```
date_count
3
2
```

For extraction you can use the following sql, you might want to add more lines based on how many dates you have max

```
with test_data as (select '2019-06-01, 2019-06-02, 2019-06-03' str_field union all
select 'This is the first date: 2019-06-01; This is the second date: 2019-06-02'
)
select regexp_substr(str_field, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',1,1) date1,
       regexp_substr(str_field, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',1,2) date2,
       regexp_substr(str_field, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',1,3) date3
  from test_data
```

Result:

```
date1       date2       date3
2019-06-01  2019-06-02  2019-06-03
2019-06-01  2019-06-02
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! It's so simple too. I wish I could also give it vote up but I don't have enough reputation points.